# StringScanner is matching a string as though it was one position back

Tags: ruby, regex, tokenize

I'm trying to use a [`StringScanner`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/strscan/rdoc/StringScanner.html) to parse a string into tokens for processing later. All was going well until I tested the regex syntax parsing. Regexen look like this:

```
r|hello|gmi
r:there|there:gmi
r/:(?=[jedi])[sith]:/gmi
r!hello!gmi
```

That is, `r`, followed by `|` (or a couple of other characters, but that's irrelevant right now), followed by the body of the regex -- which can include escaped characters, like `\|` and `\\` -- then another `|`, and then the flags of the regex.

To look for regex literals, I'm using code that looks an awful lot like this:

```
require 'strscan'
scanner = StringScanner.new('r|abc|  ')

puts "pre-regex: #{scanner.inspect}"
puts "got a char: #{scanner.getch} (res: #{scanner.inspect})"
divider = scanner.getch
puts "got divider: #{divider.inspect}"
puts "mid-regex: #{scanner.inspect}"
# this bit still fails even if you replace `#{divider}' with `|'
res = scanner.scan_until(/(?<![^\\]\\)#{divider}[a-z]*/)
puts "post-regex: #{scanner.inspect}"

if scanner.skip(/\s+/)# || scanner.skip(/;-.*?-;/m)
  puts "Success! #{res}"
else
  puts "Fail. Ended at: #{scanner.inspect}"
  puts "(res was #{res.inspect})"
end
```

<sup>[Try it online at ideone](http://ideone.com/lC3wAR)</sup>

Here, I've trimmed it down as much as I think I can to show the problem clearly. In the real code, it's part of a much large piece of code, the vast majority of which isn't relevant. I've narrowed down the bug to this part -- you can use the link to see that it's there -- but I can't figure out why this isn't correctly scanning until the next instance of `|`, then returning the flags.

As a side note, if there's a better way to do this, please let me know. I've found that I quite like `StringScanner`, but that might be because I'm obsessed with regexen, to the point that I call them regexen.

**TL;DR**: Why is `StringScanner` apparently matching as though its position was one character back, and how can I make it work right?

Comment: I deleted that comment because it's wrong. But I wonder if there are odd number  (more than 3) of pairs of backslashes before the divider, what will happen?

Comment: If there are three, I change the regex to `(?<!\\)(\\\\)*` and test better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Ruby interpolates the regexp literal with the string **as is**, for example

```
divider = '|'
/(?<![^\\]\\)#{divider}[a-z]*/
=> /(?<![^\\]\\)|[a-z]*/
```

To escape the divider, you can

```
divider = '|'
/(?<![^\\]\\)#{Regexp.quote divider}[a-z]*/
=> /(?<![^\\]\\)\|[a-z]*/
```

And this modification makes the code pass, but you still need to verify that a divider is a non-word character.

Comment: Making sure the divider is an allowed character is done elsewhere, so I'm not thinking about that. Thanks! In retrospect, this probably should have been obvious.